# passing signal with parameters from qml to c++

Tags: qt, qml

I dont know how to pass parameters from QML file to c++ file in Qt.

QML code:

```
import QtQuick 1.1

Rectangle{
    id:loin
    height: 272
    width:480
    property alias loguid:loginuid
    signal sigHome()
    Rectangle{
        id:rect1
        width:parent.width-80
        height:24
        TextInput {
            id:loginuid
            maximumLength: 16
            width: maximumLength * 20
            focus: false
            validator: RegExpValidator { regExp: /\d+/ }
            KeyNavigation.down: login1
        }
    }
    Button{
        id: login1
        x: 195
        y: 187
        height:30;
        focus:false
        border.color:"black"
        opacity: activeFocus ? 1.0 : 0.5
        Text{
        text:"LOGIN"
            anchors.horizontalCenter:login1.horizontalCenter;
            anchors.verticalCenter:login1.verticalCenter;
        }
        Keys.onReturnPressed: {
             if(loginuid.text  <  1000000000000000)
             {
                 text1.opacity=0.1
                 error1.visible=true
                 errorText.text="\n enter valid 16 digit number\n"
                 errorOk.focus=true
                 loginuid.focus=false
             }
             else{
                 loginuid.focus=false
                 loin.sigHome()
             }
        }
    }
}
```

c++ code:

```
#include <QApplication>
#include <QDeclarativeView>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QApplication app(argc, argv);
    int uid;
    QDeclarativeView view;
    view.setSource(QUrl::fromLocalFile("main.qml"));
    view.show();
    return app.exec();
}
```

When I press the login button rect1.text content shud go to main.cpp file and uid in the main.cpp get dat value. Something like this `uid=rect1.text`.
How to do it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Thanks, sebasgo, your response helped me. I used signals and slots to communicate.
I created a signal in main.qml.

```
signal info(string msg)
```

and in login page

```
else{
    info(loginUid.text)
    loginuid.focus=false
    loin.sigHome()
}
```

and in main.cpp I connected it to d slot 
main.cpp goes like this

```
#include <QtGui>
#include <QApplication>
#include <QDeclarativeView>
#include <QtDeclarative>

class DeclarativeView : public QDeclarativeView
{
    Q_OBJECT
    public:
        DeclarativeView(const QUrl & source) : QDeclarativeView(source)
        {
        }
    public slots:
        void readText(QString quid)
        {
            qdebug<<quid;
        }           
};
#include "main.moc"
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QString file = "main.qml";

    QApplication app(argc, argv);
    DeclarativeView view(QUrl::fromLocalFile(file));
    QDeclarativeItem *item = qobject_cast<QDeclarativeItem *>(view.rootObject());
    QObject::connect(item, SIGNAL(info(QString)), &view, SLOT(readText(QString)));
    view.show();
    return app.exec();
}
```

Answer (score 4):

I wouldn't try to listen for a QML signal from the C++ side. Calling a C++ method with arguments is much easier and achieves the same:

To do so you have to:

- define a [slot](http://doc-snapshot.qt-project.org/4.8/signalsandslots.html#slots) or [invokable](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qobject.html#Q_INVOKABLE) method accepting the required arguments
- [register](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qdeclarativeengine.html#qmlRegisterType) the class carrying the method with the declarative engine
- then you can [set](http://doc-snapshot.qt-project.org/4.8/qdeclarativecontext.html#setContextProperty) an instance of this class as a property of your [root context](http://doc-snapshot.qt-project.org/4.8/qdeclarativeengine.html#rootContext) and finally call this method from QML

This topic is also well covered in the [official documentation](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qml-extending.html).

Answer (score 1):

Create a GUI controller C++ class:

```
class UiController : public QObject
{
   Q_OBJECT

public:
   UiController();
   virtual ~UiController();

public slots:
   void cal_daysoff__onDoubleClicked(const QDate& date);
};
```

In QML file you define, say, a calendar control in which you connect a signal to a slot in the controller:

```
Calendar{
   id: cal_daysoff
   Layout.fillWidth: true
   Layout.fillHeight: true
   onDoubleClicked: UiController.cal_daysoff__onDoubleClicked(date)
}
```

In main file, when launching the QML interface, connect the interface to the controller:

```
#include "uicontroller.h"

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
   QApplication app(argc, argv);
   QQmlApplicationEngine engine;

   UiController control;
   engine.rootContext()->setContextProperty("UiController", &control);

   engine.load(QUrl(QStringLiteral("qrc:/main.qml")));

   return app.exec();
}
```